# why CaptiveNetwork Reference is used

Tags: iphone

I have to detect wifi networks available and need to connect using  my iPhone Application.

I found this about CaptiveNetwork Reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html)

Is this API used to detect and connect with wifi?

If this is correct can you advise of other links or other API's that might also accomplish this?

Comment: Have you read the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

No it will not allow your app to scan/detect network, it allows your app to handle the login for networks.

Meaning that if an user join a netwrok which requires a login (not via WPA or WEP) a loginsheet is presented.  If you set your app to handle the SSID kind of the networks you app wil be used to authenticate the user.

> By calling the CNSetSupportedSSIDs function, an application can
>   register a list of wireless network SSIDs with Captive Network
>   Support, thereby assuming responsibility for authenticating with those
>   networks. Typically when a user joins a captive network, Captive
>   Network Support provides a web sheet that allows the user to
>   authenticate with the network. If an application has registered the
>   SSID of the captive network, however, the web sheet is suppressed, and
>   the user can complete authentication in the appropriate application.